# Installing Fedora 17 on Mac Book Pro from mid-February

Tags: fedora, macintosh

I have problems installing Fedora on my friend's Mac Book Pro. After a boot, I get a blank screen. Forcing `nomodeset` helps:

```
nomodeset xdriver=efifb
```

However, I still cannot get into either X or text mode. Regardless of whether I try alternative drivers for X (such as vesa) or I try to enter into text mode (by adding `text` to kernel options) it fails. Does anybody have any idea how to boot the system?

Comment: Have you tried passing `boot: linux nofb` to GRUB, this should at least let you get a shell and install whatever drivers/config you need for that hardware, or at least troubleshoot more effectively.

Comment: @CharlesBoyd: The installer insisted on starting `X`. After 2 days of trying he installed Ubuntu...

Comment: Oh, well -- wasted bounty?  Perhaps someone could answer with some definitive links to installing Fedora 17 on MacBook, and maybe some talk of EFI, to provide an answer and collect bounty?

Comment: @LarsRohrbach: It doesn't look exactly as EFI problem - the console seems to work fine (except the 'little' thing about spawning `getty`) - the graphics doesn't work. My understanding is that this is well after the EFI core services are shut down but I'm not EFI expert.